# How to install apt-get without having Makefile and GCC?

Tags: c, linux, angstrom-linux

I want to install "gcc", but don't have `make`, `apt-get` and `yum`. I am using "mlinux" as OS for gateway.

Comment: I think this belongs on Unix & Linux http://unix.stackexchange.com/ not SuperUser but that's not an option for some reason.

Comment: Cross compiling is probably your best bet, but I agree with @Ben, this doesn't belong on stackoverflow.